# PHP extension is in a different location

Tags: php

I'm on Windows and I just enabled the OpenSSL extension of PHP, but when I try to run php through the command line it looks for the extension's file in C:/php when it's actually inside of C:/php5.6.4/ext

How can I tell PHP that it's looking in the wrong folder ?

Answer (score 1):

You configure PHP through php.ini.  `extension_dir` is the directive you want.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension-dir